# Remove title separator in Beamer Metropolis theme

Tags: beamer, frame-title, beamer-metropolis

I would like to disable the zero-height box separator between the subtitle and the author, inside the title slide.
On the Metropolis documentation I found only the way to change the color of the title separator, but not to remove it. How can I do?
This is my code

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=foot,numbering=none]{metropolis}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{ semantic }
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{proof}

\author{Prof. Marco Doninelli}
\title{Limiti di successioni}
\subtitle{Definizione di successione}
\date{}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

which produces
[image]

Comment: Do you want to delete that horizontal line in orange?

Comment: Yes exactly, the orange bar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That orange horizontal line separating subtitle and author is produced by the beamer template `title separator`, a new template defined by theme `metropolis` (see its source file `beamerinnerthememetropolis.sty`).

Simply redefining that template solves the problem.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=foot,numbering=none]{metropolis}

\author{Prof. Marco Doninelli}
\title{Limiti di successioni}
\subtitle{Definizione di successione}
\date{}

\setbeamertemplate{title separator}{}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To adjust the vertical space between subtitle and author, you can try

```
\setbeamertemplate{title separator}{\vspace{-10pt}\par}
```